# Do I retain patent rights after transferring copyrights?

Tags: copyright, ieee, patents

I have two questions:

1. I recently published a paper on IEEE and transferred copyrights. Can I apply for a patent after transferring copyright?
2. If I publish an article on alreadly Patented work and transfer copyright, do I lose my Patent rights?

Comment: You can no longer patent an idea if it's published.   Copyright and patent are two different things.

Comment: This should be answered by reading the contract (publication agreement).  I have never seen a publication agreement that transferred patent rights.

Comment: There's a couple close votes on this question. I'd recommend narrowing it down to one question so that people are less likely to use the close vote reason "needs more focus".

Answer (score 3):

You should contact a patent attorney for advice on this. And patent law varies over the world.

But, my best guess is that you can still obtain a patent, provided that you do so quickly. And you don't hold any patent rights until you file and the patent is awarded. Unlike copyright, patent rights aren't automatic.

Reasoning:

Copyright is about words - expression. Transferring copyright gives the new holder rights to those words, not the underlying ideas.

Patent is (normally) about devices - inventions. It isn't about ideas either, but rather "things" that have some real world effect - that are [useful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_(patent)). The "things" don't always need to be physical (software patents), but they need to fulfill the definition of a "useful" device.

However, patents won't be issued for obvious devices nor for things that are well known already. Thus, publishing your paper, independent of copyright transfer, already compromised the possibility of a patent.

But, in the US, at least, if I remember correctly, a patent can still be issued for some time after revealing the device. But only a close reading of the law, or an attorney, can advise you properly on this.

And, depending on the paper you published, the "device" you are considering might not be obvious.

---

Note that, in the US, at least, if a device is still patentable, based on your paper, someone else, who invented your device independently, could beat you to the patent. A recent change in patent law doesn't require that the patent be issued to the first person(s) who created the device, but to the "[first inventor to file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_to_file_and_first_to_invent)" for a patent. I don't understand this concept exactly, so another reason to see a lawyer. And another reason to move quickly.

Comment: I believe the current requirement to obtain a patent in the US is to be the "first inventor to file". That is, in principle you should independently invent the machine/method/whatever in order to patent it. But in case two people/teams invent the same thing independently, it will be the first to file who gets the patent rights. (Historically if there were competing claims the courts would try to sort out who was first to invent the invention, which required much more effort)

Comment: @ThePhoton, yes, I've made a few edits. I fear the new rule doesn't lessen the potential for conflict by very much, though.